# Creating a three dimensional jagged array to store two dimensional arrays of varying size in java

Tags: java

Say I have less than ten two dimensional arrays representing matrices in java.  Each array is enumerated from 0 to 6.  Each array is n*2^enumval larger where n is the number of elements from the 0th enumerated array, thus my multidimensional will almost be pyramid shaped, hence the need for a jagged three dimensional array.  Is it possible to create a jagged three dimensional array?

```
int[][] array0 = new int[2][2];
int[][] array1 = new int[4][4];
int[][] array2 = new int[8][8];
int[][] array3 = new int[16][16];
int[][][] arrayStorage = new int[][][];
```

I would like to to store the arrays with the following approach: arrayStorage[columnOfArray#][rowOfArray#][#]

Comment: It would've been simpler to just show a simple example of what kind of array you want to create instead of the prose description.

Comment: Thank you, I just went ahead and did that.  I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to create a jagged array in Java.

Here's some sample syntax for it:

```
   int[][] jagged = new int[3][];
   jagged[0] = new int[]{1, 2, 4};
   jagged[1] = new int[]{9, 17, 35, 80};
   jagged[2] = new int[]{100};
```

In this, I have a jagged array with three rows but an indeterminate amount of columsn.  THeir lengths vary from 1 to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Java *only* supports jagged arrays. An example of the sort of 3D array (using a "list" of "matrices" as a more relatable concrete example) you're looking for:

```
// an array of m*n (or jagged) 2D arrays.
int[][][] matrices = new int[2][][];

// A 2*2 matrix
int[][] matrix22 = new int[2][];
matrix22[0] = new int[] {1, 2};
matrix22[1] = new int[] {3, 4};

matrices[0] = matrix22;

// A 3*3 matrix
int[][] matrix33 = new int[3][];
matrix33[0] = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
matrix33[1] = new int[] {4, 5, 6};
matrix33[2] = new int[] {7, 8, 9};

matrices[1] = matrix33;
```

Or, golfed to one statement:

```
int[][][] matrices2 = new int[][][] {
    new int[][] {
        new int[] {1, 2},
        new int[] {3, 4}
    },
    new int[][] {
        new int[] {1, 2, 3},
        new int[] {4, 5, 6},
        new int[] {7, 8, 9}
    }
};
```